# Compass config.rb print to console

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Can anyone tell me if its possible to print to the console from within the compass config.rb file?

I have custom function within this file and want to check the contents of a variable.

Thanks

Comment: Try `$logger.log("here");`

Comment: By 'console', do you mean the browser console? or the terminal where compass watch runs?

Comment: The terminal where compass runs when its compiling.

Comment: Can you try `puts "#{your_variable}"` ?

Comment: ty, crmpicco, the following worked

puts variable_name